# Does Onaas Devarim apply to non-Jews?

Tags: gentiles, middos-character-traits, bein-adam-lachavero

I know that it is a serious aveirah to hurt a Jew's feelings. But is it an aveirah to hurt a non-Jew's feelings as well?

Comment: Yes, for example Moshe and Aharon were commanded to speak respectfully to Pharoh, and Esther lost her divine inspiration because she insulted Achashveirosh.

Comment: Consider Mesilat Yisharim ch.18. Not a halachic answer necessarily but relevant to anyone seeking to do the right thing

Comment: See in Pereq Gid Hanashe about Niqur.